# Merging overlapping GeoJSON LineStrings (Tippecanoe) and add visualization

Tags: geojson, linestring, visualisation, tippecanoe

I would like to merge overlapping GeoJSON LineStrings and visually style merged LineString. I have a database of GeoJSON LineStrings which represent routes people drove. I would like to visualize routes which people drive most frequent with different colour than the ones that are not that frequently driven.

Example of Tippecanoe rendered Mbtiles of GeoJSON LineStrings (numbers stand for overlapping routes):

[image]

And I would like to achieve something similar to what I depicted on image bellow:

[image]

I came across few articles how to visualize GeoJSON Points, but I can not find any helpful tip how to achieve the visualization for LineStrings.

Technologies that I'm using: MongoDB, Tippecanoe (https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe), tileserver-gl (https://github.com/maptiler/tileserver-gl)

Ideally I would like to achieve similar results that Strava has:

[image]

I don't know if technologies I'm using are good fit to achieve that.